# Access Kubernets API from a different cluster

Tags: kubernetes, cloud

Assume we have a system with multiple K8s clusters with one management cluster acting as Control plane and multiple data plane clusters for deploying apps, services etc.

I need to manage data plane clusters (query, create, update, delete resources) via an application running on control plane cluster. I'm thinking of achieving this by accessing the K8s API.

So I need to know what are the possible ways to do this, rather than just exposing K8s API of data plane clusters to the control plane cluster.

As I found from the internet, one way to achieve this by having an agent in each data plane cluster and that agents will be connecting to a central server in control plane cluster.

Are there any other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's in your control plane cluster and how it interacts with the data plane.

Answering the general scenario if you have multiple clusters of data planes and just want to manage the resources like **service**, **apps**, **deployment**, **ingress** you can use the **Helm** or **Kustomize** and simply apply the template to data plane from control plane.

If your control plane is creating a different git repos for managing it one **deployment**  you can use the [Flux](https://fluxcd.io/) in the data plane cluster which will sync resources from Git.

You can simply use the **kubeconfig** with Kubectl or Helm and deploy the resources from the control plane to the data plane as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. In my control plane I will be running a separate application and I need to manage resources via that application (i.e. without manual interaction).

Comment: In that case, you can also use the kubeconfig file, and rest API for auth. it's more now on to the requirement single push required or sync required. you can save endpoint details or config file and with client you can access cluster and do changes.